# Adding Action Event to Look and Feel menu item

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I made a Desktop application. I made it using Netbeans 7 IDE.

In it, I have created a menu called look and feel. I created it by dragging the menu from palette. The menu items are Window,Metal and Motif. I want the look and feel to change on menu item selection. The menu items are checkbox menu items. I right clicked on the menu item and selected event in netbeans and added a few codes. But when I select the menu item after running the project, nothing happens and the GUI gets frozen.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use radio buttons instead.Now to your problem,

> ..and added a few codes.

I'm not sure what these codes are, but I guess this might be missing,

> To make existing components reflect the new L&F, invoke the SwingUtilities updateComponentTreeUI method once per top-level container.

So after this,

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfName);
```

You need to these too,

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working now. I used the following code in the onItemStateChanged event of radio button ---- try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
      SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      
    }

Comment: Yes. But don't know much about regulations and all. :-)